# Как изменить код для разных версий JQUERY?

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток!

Код проверяет заполненность формы, если по нажатию на "Отправить данные" поля ввода не заполнены их border окрашивается в красный цвет и отправить форму невозможно, до тех пор пока все поля не будут заполнены.(Смотрите код, ниже)

Проблем не возникает с версией JQUERY 1.8.1
c кодом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Простая проверка полей формы</title>
 
 <style>
 .form_box input {
 display: block;
 border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #444444;
 padding: 7px 7px 8px;
 width: 250px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .form_box input:focus {
 outline: none;
 border-color: #07a6e6;
    }
    .form_box .btn_submit {
 border: none;
 width: 180px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #07a6e6;
 font-size: 13px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #ffffff;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 35px;
 line-height: 28px;
 padding: 0;
    }
    .form_box .btn_submit.disabled{
 background: #afdde6;
 cursor: default;
    }

 </style>
 
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
 <div class="form_box">
  
  <form action="#" method="post" class="rf">
   <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" />

   <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" />
   
   <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" />
   
   <input type="submit" class="btn_submit disabled" value="Отправить данные" />   
  </form>
  
 </div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {

 $(function() {

  $('.rf').each(function(){
   var form = $(this),
    btn = form.find('.btn_submit');
   
   form.find('.rfield').addClass('empty_field');
   
   // Функция проверки полей формы
   function checkInput(){
    form.find('.rfield').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() != ''){
      $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
     } else {
      $(this).addClass('empty_field');
     }
    });
   }
   
   // Функция подсветки незаполненных полей
   function lightEmpty(){
    form.find('.empty_field').css({'border-color':'red'});
    setTimeout(function(){
     form.find('.empty_field').removeAttr('style');
    },1000);
   }
   
            setInterval(function(){
    checkInput();
    var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').size();
    if(sizeEmpty > 0){
     if(btn.hasClass('disabled')){
      return false
     } else {
      btn.addClass('disabled')
     }
    } else {
     btn.removeClass('disabled')
    }
   },1000);


            btn.click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
     lightEmpty();
     return false
    } else {
     form.submit();
    }
   });   
  });  
   });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Как использовать выше предоставленный код с версией **JQUERY 3.4.1**?
Если заменить jquery(1.8.1) `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
на jquery(3.4.1) `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

То в консоле появится ошибка 
**Uncaught TypeError: form.find(...).size is not a function** и код перестаёт работать как работал на версии Jquery 1.8.1.

Как сделать чтобы этот код на Jquery 3.4.1 работал , также как и на Jqery 1.8.1?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
form.find('.empty_field').length;
```

это работает и с 1.8.1.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $(function() {

    $('.rf').each(function() {
      var form = $(this),
        btn = form.find('.btn_submit');

      form.find('.rfield').addClass('empty_field');

      // Функция проверки полей формы
      function checkInput() {
        form.find('.rfield').each(function() {
          if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
          } else {
            $(this).addClass('empty_field');
          }
        });
      }

      // Функция подсветки незаполненных полей
      function lightEmpty() {
        form.find('.empty_field').css({
          'border-color': 'red'
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
          form.find('.empty_field').removeAttr('style');
        }, 1000);
      }

      setInterval(function() {
        checkInput();
        var sizeEmpty = form.find('.empty_field').length;
        if (sizeEmpty > 0) {
          if (btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false
          } else {
            btn.addClass('disabled')
          }
        } else {
          btn.removeClass('disabled')
        }
      }, 1000);


      btn.click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
          lightEmpty();
          return false
        } else {
          form.submit();
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.form_box input {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #444444;
  padding: 7px 7px 8px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.form_box input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #07a6e6;
}

.form_box .btn_submit {
  border: none;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #07a6e6;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0;
}

.form_box .btn_submit.disabled {
  background: #afdde6;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div class="form_box">

    <form action="#" method="post" class="rf">
      <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_name" />

      <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_family" />

      <input type="text" class="rfield" id="user_phone" />

      <input type="submit" class="btn_submit disabled" value="Отправить данные" />
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```